# how to set maximum and minimum number can be entered in a TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers

I want a text box that will only get 1-24 numbers. I want it to check the 1st digit as it must be 1 or 2 also. If the user give any other inputs, it will show a warning in a message box.
it is the code that I have tried :

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int hour;
    bool ishourValid = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out hour);

    // Check the Text value if it's only numbers
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox2.Text, "[^0-9]"))
    {
        // Clear the text box as it wasn't a number
        textBox2.Clear();
        // Show Warning MesssageBox
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter numbers only!");
    }
    // Check TextBox text length
    else if (textBox2.Text.Length >= 2)
    {
        textBox6.Focus();
    }
    else if (Hour < 1 && Hour > 24)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please use 24-hour format!");
    }
}
```

Everything is working but this code is not working :

```
else if (Hour < 1 && Hour > 24)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please use 24-hour format!");
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: '(Hour < 1 && Hour > 24)' I think you should use "or" here rather than "and".

Comment: True condition: `Hour >= 0 && Hour < 24`

Comment: Why not use a NumericUpDown instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: isHourValid is a good start but you are not using it. Add the check (hour >= 0 || hour < 24) immediately after it. Get rid of the RegEx, it is wrong,  It checks the entire string, not just the character added. Do not delete the user's input, that is so annoying. Do not shout at the user either!

Comment: As you can see this text box is for getting the time from the user. So, there must be only numbers. if the user press any other key accidentally then it will be cleared with `textBox2.Clear();`. should I avoid clearing the user input @Martin ?

Comment: I mean let the user correct his/her own errors. And it is better to at least wait until he/she moves to the next field. No one likes to be terminated in the middle of something. Besides, they won't be looking, they wil be typing.

Comment: And your RegEx is OK, I was wrong about that. You just need either the conversion or the RegEx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning you try to parse the string value from textBox2.Text and store it into 'hour'.

```
int hour;
bool ishourValid = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out hour);
```

Later on you are checking `Hour`...
    else if (Hour < 1 && Hour > 24)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please use 24-hour format!");
    }

But you haven't ever set `Hour`.  You set `hour`.  I can't see where `Hour` is defined; it must be somewhere if you are able to compile.  My guess is that your code isn't working as expected because you need something like:

```
Hour = hour;
```

or change your TryParse to use Hour...

```
bool ishourValid = int.TryParse(txt, out Hour);
```

Having said that, I think there are few more issues.  This might be a better fit on the Code Review Stack?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rob .It is working well now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the code would work if you did not capitalize hour? Plus it looks like the evaluation was looking for an answer that was less than 1 and more than 24 at the same time.

Old:
`else if (Hour < 1 && Hour > 24)`

New:
`else if (hour < 1 || hour > 24)`

Answer (score 0):

you need a `||` (`OR`) condition instead of `AND` condition. change your code to be like below else the value of `Hour` at any point in time can't hold both boundary value. Meant to say, if `Hour < 1` then no way it can be greater than 24 and your condition bound to be evaluate to false.

```
else if (Hour < 1 || Hour > 24)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please use 24-hour format!");
}
```